# Can a slaad control gem be used to command a slaad that's on a different plane?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, planes

The PCs fought a dark elf and a gray slaad. The PCs killed the dark elf, but the gray slaad used *plane shift* to escape. The PCs found among the dark elf's gear the gray slaad's control gem.

1. Must a PC attune to the slaad control gem to be able to use it?
2. Further, after attuning to the control gem if necessary, can the PC
   use the control gem to cause the slaad to return to the PC's plane,
   or is the slaad uncontrollable forevermore after it leaves the plane
   where its control gem resides?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Have you taken the [tour]? As written we won't be able to this question. Mainly, what edition of the game are you playing? This has a huge bearing on the answer to this question. If you [edit] this information into the question we will be able to provide a much better answer.